# Is it possible to run multiple powershell scripts, in order, with waiting for completion before launching next?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, powershell, powershell-ise

I have 3 Powershell ISE scripts.

Script1.ps1, Script2.ps1, Script3.ps1

Is it possible to run all scripts, in the order given? When i am asking this i am not suggesting parallel behaviour, but rather a synchronious one. To execute script2, it must wait for script1 to finish, to execute script3 it must wait for script2 to finish, etc.

Cheers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.\script1.ps1
.\script2.ps1
.\stript3.ps1
```

All in a *.ps1 file that'll be started in PS by yourself.

Comment: however if the first fails, will the second be executed?

Comment: exactly, i need the whole process to halt if one one of the scripts failed.

Comment: In this case return a value from your first script, and if it's an error, just don't call a script.

Comment: thank you, will try, as an observation it would seem not many people are familiar with powershell altough it is a pretty powerfull tool.

Comment: Have you checked out [PowerShell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/), [WindowsITPro](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/my-12-powershell-best-practices), or [PowerShell Magazine](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/category/brain-teasers/) there are crazy smart people with PowerShell (I'm looking at you Shay). You just have to ask harder questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
for($i=1;$i-le3;$i++){
    & ".\script$i.ps1"
    if(!$?){
         Write-Error "Script $i failed; Exiting"
         return (-1)
    }
}
```

$? returns true if the last command ran successfully.